# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'custom-input'

Tags: angular, plunker

I am trying to create a custom input named "form-select"

I have been successfully did it on my Angular CLI project. But there I am not able to call **(change)** event.

So I decided to replicate it in plunker and then post a question in Stack Overflow.

But while I was trying to replicate that in plunker, after completing all step I found the following error.

> Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known
>   property of 'form-select'.

Can anyone please help me to setup the plunker and run the code seccessfully.
So that I acn replicate the next issue.

Here is the plunker link :

https://plnkr.co/edit/M0giak8joHCmxXWXgm4o?p=preview

My Component Signature is as follows.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'form-select',
  templateUrl: './src/form-select.component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormSelectComponent),
    multi: true,
  }]
})
export class FormSelectComponent extends ElementBase<string> implements OnInit {
}
```

**EDIT**

**trichetriche** Thanks a lot for the help.
Now I am getting a different error as

> TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.of is not a function

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `ngModel` needs the `FormsModule` to work. Try to import that in your module ?

Comment: A Basic Mistake. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Understandable, we all have been there. Good luck !

Comment: Now how do I remove this question from Stack Overflow?

Comment: That's a very good question, I don't know, I only care to answer here

Comment: The problem comes from you `validate.ts` file on line 55 : You are supposed to return an Observable in this function, but it seems you're not returning it when you provide async validators.

Comment: Solved the problem. Now it is running. Thanks a lot. You could post all those answer in a post and I will vote it up.

Comment: No problem, remember to marj it as resolved !